# Code doesn't work properly after using a while: try: loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, try-catch

I had to do a python exercise for school.

This is my code:

```
print("Animal-determiner")
while True:
    try:
        amount =  int(input("How many animals do you want to determine? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That was not a number.")
    else:
        break

while amount > 0:
    legs = int(input("How may legs does the animal have? "))

    if legs < 0:
        print("Such an animal doesn't exist.")
    elif legs == 1 or 3:
        print("Such an animal doesn't exist.")
    elif legs == 0:
        water = input("Does the animal live in water? ")
        if water is "yes":
            print("This is a fish")
        elif water is "no":
            print("This is a snake.")
        else:
            print("You didn't put in yes or no.")
    elif legs == 2:
        fly = input("Can the animal fly? ")
        if vliegen is "yes":
            print("This is a bird.")
        elif vliegen is "no":
            print("This has to be a bird, which can't fly.")
        else:
            print("You didn't put in yes or no.")
    elif legs == 4:
        print("This is getting to complicated, I'm stopping")

    amount -= 1
```

But when i run this code it always says: "Such an animal doesn't exist." even if i put in a: 0 or a 4 which should give back something different

help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your line "elif legs == 1 or 3" you are asking "if 3", which returns true. Rewrite it as: "elif legs == 1 or legs == 3"

Comment: The problem here has been answered. For future references, you can add a different `print` statement after each `elif` condition, or a `print(legs)` before the `if`; that way it is easier for you to find where the problem is. You can then delete them or comment them once the program works

Answer (score 0):

The condition `elif legs == 1 or 3:` is wrong, it should be `elif legs == 1 or legs == 3:` or `elif legs in (1, 3):`

Answer (score 0):

`legs == 1 or 3` - that doesn't work like that. `3` will be evaluated as a condition. Because it is nonzero, it evaluates as `True`. [`or`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_or.asp) does not work like you may think - it is for checking if at **least one of two conditions are `True`**. And because `3` is `True`, the expression will be `True`. Use `in`:

```py
legs in (1, 3)
```

[`in`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) checks if something is a collection.